# How do I add a hidden file using a command prompt and PowerShell?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, powershell-3.0

What is the command to create a hidden file via command prompt and PowerShell?

- by hidden I mean that it wont be visible but still exists.

I have tried but I still do not know how.

thank you.

Comment: create the file normally and set the hidden attribute?

Answer (score 0):

As @LưuVĩnhPhúc said in his comment you can create a new file:

`New-Item foo.bar`

and then set the 'hidden' attribute of the file:

`(Get-Item foo.bar).Attributes += [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden`